Electric noise when changing power governer
I use arch linux on IdeaPad L3 15IML05 laptop
the cpu driver in use is intel_pstate as stated here:
     ~  λ  cpupower frequency-info
  driver: intel_pstate
  CPUs which run at the same hardware frequency: 3
  CPUs which need to have their frequency coordinated by software: 3
  maximum transition latency:  Cannot determine or is not supported.
  hardware limits: 400 MHz - 4.90 GHz
  available cpufreq governors: performance powersave
  current policy: frequency should be within 400 MHz and 4.90 GHz.
                  The governor "powersave" may decide which speed to use
                  within this range.
  current CPU frequency: Unable to call hardware
  current CPU frequency: 2.12 GHz (asserted by call to kernel)
  boost state support:
    Supported: yes
    Active: yes

The problem is that when i switch to performance governor using the command
cpupower frequency-set -g performance

An electric noise comes from the laptop.
the character of the noise was faint and going up and down every second. and it becomes more constant with increased load.
The questions I have.

is how can i stop this sound?
is this a sign that i shouldn't use this mode , is it degrading my cpu?
is it something related to software or hardware?
could it possibly be a short circuit or something physical?

notes: I have an ssd.

I'm sorry. Have u ever used linux? Electric noise is noise like the noise when you plug your fridge in an old socket. And power governor is the software that decides on a CPU frequency.

@DrMoishePippik: Come on, they even included the cpupower output in the question. Cpufreq "governors" are the Linux mechanism of setting CPU frequency scaling (the one named "performance" – as in the output – aims towards highest frequency). Don't rush to downvote anything that's unfamiliar.

What do you mean by "electric noise"? By "the noise when you plug your fridge in an old socket?"

youtube video . something like this but it's throbbing in nature. i don't really know how to explain the sound. I after some research i think it's coil whine. but is it normal to be peaking every second.?
